# NLTK: TypeError: must be str, not list

Tags: python, django, nlp, nltk, newspaper3k

I'm using newspaper3k in a docker container. I downloaded all the needed nltk data, however I'm having this problem when I run `article.nlp()` then `article.nlp()` and `article.summary`.

When I used the same code in a Flask app it worked, now I'm testing it on a Django (+ DRF), and I'm having this errors:

```
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/newspaper/article.py", line 361, in nlp
web_1  |     summary_sents = nlp.summarize(title=self.title, text=self.text, max_sents=max_sents)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/newspaper/nlp.py", line 45, in summarize
web_1  |     sentences = split_sentences(text)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/newspaper/nlp.py", line 157, in split_sentences
web_1  |     tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 752, in load
web_1  |     opened_resource = _open(resource_url)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 877, in _open
web_1  |     return find(path_, path + [""]).open()
web_1  | TypeError: must be str, not list
```

It seems that there's a problem finding `tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle`, but when I check the nltk_data, it's there.

Do you have any idea, from where this may come?

**Update**:

The code is very simple. This is my Django view:

```
from newspaper import Article

article = Article(url, language=LANG)
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp() <---- The problem happens here most probably
article.summary
```

Since I'm using Django Rest Framwork, I'm serializing using this field:

```
summary = serializers.CharField(max_length=5000, required=False)
```

Comment: usually, when you get this error it means that you are passing a list to an attribute that is expecting a string and not a list. I cant help that much since you didn't share your code. try to debug your code.

Comment: what if you explicitly define the protocol: `tokenizer = nltk.data.load('nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')`

Comment: @HozayfaElRifai I added the code.

Comment: @Ehsan I tried that. It changes nothing.

Comment: also try this after Article import `nltk.download(['punkt'])`

Comment: Nothing happens. I even ran nltk.download("all")

Comment: Are you sure the link you are passing to the ```Article``` is a string and not a list?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing it to similar functions, and it works with newspaper.

Comment: The problem is happening at this level: https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/9b89046d076b244fef006aee1a485b1f6e537bdf/newspaper/article.py#L372

Comment: Take a look at the NLP section of my newspaper3k overview document, which is available here:  https://github.com/johnbumgarner/newspaper3_usage_overview#text-extraction-and-natural-language-processing.